# simple communication between two XBee modules

Tags: wifi, xbee, zigbee

I searched and couldn't find this question in the forum. Maybe because it's so novice:)

I have a pair of XB24 modules. I have connected them both to my laptop through USB adapters. one of these for each of the modules:
[image]

This is the function set I've flashed into one of them (router AT) and its firmware version. 
[image]

And this is the function set (coordinator AT) and its firmware version for the other 
[image]

These are the settings for the coordinator:
[image]

and these are settings for the router:
[image]
[image]
They both have their power level set to 4 (highest) and they are both turned on. But as you can see, router's network address is 0xFFFE which to my knowledge means it's not joined a network. And the communication doesn't take place when I open up two serial connections in XCTU. What am I doing wrong? Is this setup even supposed to work? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was issue (ATRE,ATWR) commands on both coordinator and router. And after setting ID and destination addresses again, I issued a network reset command (ATNR0) on each. then router joined coordinator and serial communication worked without a problem.